# Python selenium find elements issue

Tags: python, selenium

How can I get the first 8 elements retrieved by the below selenium code;

```
   items1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='imports']/div[*]/div/div[3]/div[*]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[text()[starts-with(.,'25.2')]]")
```

To be in this form below;

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("[@id='imports']/div[*]/div/div[3]/div[*]/div[2]/div/div[" + str(randomNumber) + "]").click()
```

The deal is to search a webpage and get the list of items that begins with 25.2. and then select the first 8 elements of the list in the form noted... Help and suggestions needed.

Comment: Share HTML and specify current and desired output

Comment: Hm , maybe i dont understand. But if you get the all elements with that 25.2. You can easy do for loop and use findelements("whatever").get(i) . i will go from 0 to 7.